# Woocommerce place order in the product page

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages, woocommerce-theming

In WooCommerce, I need to make the user place the order directly from the product page, by adding some custom checkout fields to the product page with the 'place order' button.
Like in [this website](https://dev.wooecom.com/product/dnk-blue-shoes/).

I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: Welcome! Remember that Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Please share what you have tried to solve the issue, a minimal example can be usefull, and a specific error of the code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do not ask for coding this, I need your ideas about the better way to do it, should I change woocommerce template or should I use hooks and should I customize default checkout form or create custom one from scratch

Comment: The example is for COD payment method so create function for creating order on pressing a button with some validation if fields are filled etc and populate your data in the order after creation redirect to custom page where you say the order is complete. Thats all